# Inferring matrices from given products of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my research, I encountered the following problem. If someone were given the following matrix products, is it possible for them to infer the value of any of the original matrices ($A, B, C, X, Y, Z$)?

$X^T X, Y^T Y, Z^T Z$

$X^T Y, X^T Z,Y^T Z$

$A^T Y, A^T Z, B^T Z, A^T B, A^T C, B^T C$

where $X, A \in \mathbb{R}^{f \times n_A}$, $Y, B \in \mathbb{R}^{f \times n_B}$ and $Z, C \in \mathbb{R}^{f \times n_C}$. $f$ is not given, and based on the given matrix products, it can't be inferred (as far as I can see).

My intuition is that it is not possible to infer any of these matrices since $f$ is unknown. So you can't infer the dimension of any of the input matrices. However, I couldn't prove it mathematically.

Comment: Why do you mix upper and lowercase ? Do you call dot product the product of matrices ?

Comment: What/who is the "third party" ???

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the products of matrices. I edited the question. What I mean by "third-party" is basically someone who has these products of the matrices.

Comment: I forgot one of the matrices. I added that one too.

Answer (score 0):

There are $u:=2f(n_a+n_b+n_c)$ unknown matrix elements and $e:=(n_a+n_b+n_c)^2$ equations. Even if $f$ is known, the system can be indeterminate. And in the case of as many equations as there are unknowns ($u=e$), there can be up to $2^e$ solutions as the equations are quadratic !